# In Vim can I automatically soft wrap comments with alignment at the first character

Tags: auto-indent

I'm currently using vim to take notes and the way I'll usually do that is as follows:

```
- First line of info
    - Sub line of info
    - More sub information
- Second point
- Third point, etc
```

However, when writing long lines the output will look as follows:

```
- First line of info that is really long
goes down to here
    - Subpoint line of info that is short
    - Subpoint line that is really long goes to
    here and continues
    - Subpoint line that is short again
- Second point that is really long goes to
here, etc, etc
```

What I'd really like is if it looked like this:

```
- First line of info that is really long
  goes down to here
    - Subpoint line of info that is short
    - Subpoint line that is really long goes to
      here and continues
    - Subpoint line that is short again
- Second point that is really long goes to
  here, etc, etc
```

This would make it easier to see when each new point or subpoint was started because of the "-" sticks out more.

If possible I'd like:

1. automatic inserting of the leading character (doesn't have to be a dash) on enter
2. automatic inserting of the leading character (doesn't have to be a dash) on o and O
3. automatic soft wrapping of the text to the correct indentation level
4. automatic soft wrapping of the text to the first character after the leading character

I've been able to achieve the first three using the following:

```
set formatoptions=ro
set comments=b:-
set breakindent
set autoindent
```

However, when trying to get the soft wrapping at the first character after the "-" I am having trouble.
I've tried using `set formatoptions+=n` with an accompanying `formatlistpat=^\s*-\s*`. However, then it is not automatic and I need to use `gq` which seems like it makes a second line instead of just soft wrapping. If using `set formatoptions+=wan` I can get it sometimes automatically wrapping but it is once again a hard line break, not a soft wrapping.

If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So I've finally figured it out. The answer was breakindentopt `:help breakindentopt`

Specifically `set breakindentopt=shift:2`

This causes the line that is wrapped due to breakindent to shift two spaces two the right which lines everything up the way I wanted.

The full settings which achieve what I was going for are:

```
set formatoptions=ro
set comments=b:-
set breakindent
set autoindent
set breakindentopt=shift:2
```

Comment: Super helpful, thank you!